# How to set a Ctrl+Up+Left to move window to the top and left corner in KDE Plasma?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, shortcuts, plasma, kwin

I'm working in KDE Neon with Plasma, but I can't set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> as a shortcut to do this movement.

When I click in the Kwin shortcuts action to do that I press these three keys and the system says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) is already set to do another action. How can I set these three keys for that action?

I tried to disable these others functions first, but anyway, the system doesn't recognize these three keys together.

I was looking for a way to edit the shortcuts from Konsole, but I haven't found it.

Comment: KDE neon is supported at our related site [unix.se], [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: Since, other than being off-topic, this is a good question, and since it has a valuable answer, it seems to me that it would be a good idea for this to be migrated to [unix.se]. @JusticeforMonica

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100937/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-justice-for-monica).

Answer (score 3):

The image below is of the user interface KDE Plasma provides in Kubuntu 18.04, for setting up the type of shortcuts of interest (*System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > KWin*).

KDE Plasma provides for, among other things, options for moving windows to the

- top left
- bottom left
- top right and
- bottom right

corners of your screen.

[image: Quick Tile Windows to Corners]

Points to note

- You can have two modifier keys but not two non-modifier keys in a shortcut. (Modifier keys are <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Meta</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>.)
- A combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> isn't recognized.
- If a keyboard shortcut you choose is already used by something, you'll get a pop-up;  if you wish, you can click *Reassign* to make the shortcut work for the action of your choice.

Comment: `A combination such as Ctrl+Left+Up isn't recognized.` Why? Sounds like a bad design. It's a useful feature to implement and can't be that hard...